# Spock testing - variables getting null value from the new operator

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, spock

Below is my test code,

```
def 'test write then update with commit after all operations parallely'() {
    given:
    def outputPath = "writeThenUpdateWithCommitAfterAllOperationsParallely.csv"
    csvManipulator = new CsvManipulator(RESOURCE_PATH, outputPath, FIELD_COUNT, 0
            , new ResourceReaderProvider(), new FileWriterProvider())

    when:
    GParsPool.withPool 100, {
        (0..LOOP-1).eachParallel { row ->
            writeThenUpdate(row, false)
        }
    }
    csvManipulator.commit()

    then:
    Reader reader = new FileReader(outputPath)
    def outputRawCsv = IOUtils.toString(reader)
    expectedRawCsv == outputRawCsv

    cleanup:
    reader.close()
    Files.delete(Paths.get(outputPath))
}
```

In short, during debugging mode at each line, I saw all variables `outputPath`, `csvManipulator` ... and `reader` (in the `then` block) are all **null**.

Hence, the test ends up in the `NullPointerException` occurs during closing the null reader.

And that how it looks like in debugging mode:  (you can see all the variables are null)

[image: intellij]

What happens?

Comment: I have never seen this before :-). Can you provide a .zip file with the project. Or even better can you reproduce this in a small project and share this?

Comment: You should provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something we can build + run. Obviously we are not seeing the full picture: The Spock spec is just a fragment, not the whole class. I also cannot see the subject under test, i.e. the application class(es) in question. I doubt the problem is in Spock, probably something is wrong with your code or with the way you build (something like outdated class files or whatever).

Comment: You can get the file content in groovy with `def outputRawCsv  = new File(outputPath).text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Spock Documentation: "The when and then blocks always occur together. They describe a stimulus and the expected response. Whereas when blocks may **contain arbitrary code**, **then blocks are restricted to conditions, exception conditions, interactions, and variable definitions**. A feature method may contain multiple pairs of when-then blocks." [Spock blocks](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_blocks)

These two lines:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(outputPath)
def outputRawCsv = IOUtils.toString(reader)
```

Need to be in the above when block as shown below:

```
def 'test write then update with commit after all operations parallely'() {
    given:
    def outputPath = "writeThenUpdateWithCommitAfterAllOperationsParallely.csv"
    csvManipulator = new CsvManipulator(RESOURCE_PATH, outputPath, FIELD_COUNT, 0
            , new ResourceReaderProvider(), new FileWriterProvider())

    when:
    GParsPool.withPool 100, {
        (0..LOOP-1).eachParallel { row ->
            writeThenUpdate(row, false)
        }
    }
    csvManipulator.commit()
    Reader reader = new FileReader(outputPath)
    def outputRawCsv = IOUtils.toString(reader)

    then:
    expectedRawCsv == outputRawCsv

    cleanup:
    reader.close()
    Files.delete(Paths.get(outputPath))
}
```

I would also consider reading the file in using the method Leonard suggested:

```
def outputRawCsv = new File(outputPath).text
```

Adding everything in:

```
def 'test write then update with commit after all operations parallely'() {
    given:
    def outputPath = "writeThenUpdateWithCommitAfterAllOperationsParallely.csv"
    csvManipulator = new CsvManipulator(RESOURCE_PATH, outputPath, FIELD_COUNT, 0
            , new ResourceReaderProvider(), new FileWriterProvider())

    when:
    GParsPool.withPool 100, {
        (0..LOOP-1).eachParallel { row ->
            writeThenUpdate(row, false)
        }
    }
    csvManipulator.commit()
    def outputRawCsv = new File(outputPath).text

    then:
    expectedRawCsv == outputRawCsv

    cleanup:
    reader.close()
    Files.delete(Paths.get(outputPath))
}
```

If this doesn't work going to need the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, you hacked the problem!  *then blocks are restricted to conditions, exception conditions, interactions, and variable definitions*. I/O related stuffs shouldn't be put within the then block. Moving it off solves the problem.